# Account Linking on Actions on Google Step by step

Tags: oauth-2.0, linker, webserver, account, actions-on-google

I'm new at Actions on Google and I've never done account linking. I'd like to link my web server with Google account. Can anyone explain me how to do account linking step by step. I found link https://developers.google.com/actions/develop/identity/account-linking but when I run simulation it says "It looks like your apial account is not linked yet. You can link apial to your Google Account from the Google Home app.". What am I supposed to do next?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the web simulator, when it states *"It looks like your XYZ account is not linked yet"*, it'll provide something like the following on the response log on the right:

```
"name": "Account Linking Url",
"debugInfo": "https://assistant.google.com/services/auth/handoffs/auth/start?provider=google-project-id-123455_dev&return_url=https://www.google.com/"
```

You can copy & paste that link into your browser, and it'll take you to the OAuth provider that you set up, asking you to authorize your API.AI app. If the process succeeds, you'll eventually be redirected to `https://www.google.com/?result_code=SUCCESS&result_message=Accounts+now+linked`, as an indication that the process worked.

Of course, if you have an actual Google Home, you can open your Google Home app and follow the process there instead.

Comment: Which value "accessTokenUrl" should have?

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean? First question, are you actually using API.AI to create your action, or do you use the actions-on-google SDK? I assumed the former, because it says "apiai" in your original query. So then, you're talking about the OAuth information that you have to enter in Integrations/Actions On Google? That information depends on how your webserver is set up, in particular your OAuth service. So there's no generic answer.