# Google agent authorization flow doesn't proceed after the grantType=authorization_code request

Tags: actions-on-google, api-ai

I am developing a API AI agent, and trying to implement the account linking functionality. The documentation at [oauth2-codeflow](https://developers.google.com/actions/identity/oauth2-code-flow) is really helpful and I am able to create my oauth flow and test the same in [Google playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground/). It all works fine till here.

But when I am trying to test it in the web simulator, I keep getting the "It looks like your Agent account is not linked yet". I've followed the debug URL and proceeded with the login and authorization steps.

As per this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41330516/account-linking-on-actions-on-google-step-by-step): I should be expecting the browser to be redirected to `https://www.google.com/?result_code=SUCCESS&result_message=Accounts+now+linked`, but my browser always gets redirected to `https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=QDOEWfCAPMHA0gSUvJj4Ag` and in the agent I still get `accounts not linked` message.

I can see that Google is able to invoke my tokens endpoint with grantType:authorization_code and my service responds as outlined below:

```
POST for /myendpoint/tokens has begun for: grantType:authorization_code  clientId:google-clientid...8
```

My service response is:

```
{
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "access_token":"ab092868.....e804bcac",
  "refresh_token":"e11e6d3054883...b30",
  "expires_in":3600
}
```

I've gone through the suggestion in the [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43113595/actions-on-google-and-account-linking-failure-after-tokens-returned) but my response has no additional parameters. It is plain and simple

I am sending the above response through a nodejs application with following code:

```
    res.setHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-store');
    res.setHeader('Pragma', 'no-cache');
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json;charset=UTF-8');
    res.send(JSON.stringify(respObj));
```

I am really struck now, and couldn't find a way out! Kindly help.

Comment: Looking at the https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6749#section-5.1 I've added the additional headers to the response, but still no use!

Comment: The access token and refresh token are of length 276 chars. As per RFC the the client should not assume or predict the length of the tokens, but not sure if google is looking for specific length of the tokens, can someone please help!

Comment: Phani, I'm not seeing anything obviously wrong based on what you've provided in your questiogn. It appears likely something in our redirect chain isn't behaving as expected. Can you give me your Provider ID (the provider= field used by the Simulator?), so that I can take a look at our logging and run some tests? If you don't want to post it here, you can provide it by e-mail.

Comment: Thank you @foxxtrot I couldn't find a way to send you a mail. I've sent the provider and other  details in a mail to Ahmed and Sachit. Can you kindly get the details from them and help me further with the issue?

Answer (score 2):

As noted via e-mail, it appears that you are not redirecting to the same URL as the redirect_uri parameter that is provided to your Authorization Endpoint during the sign-in flow. I am going to investigate improving the messaging around this error.

Comment: Jeff, but as explained in the email, even after  correcting the redirect uri, it still is not working. Also thank you for your prompt response. As you mentioned in your further response, kindly see what is the problem with web simulator and why web simulator is not working as intended for oauth flow.

Comment: I'm seeing the exact same issue from the UK and my app keeps being rejected even though I've tested the flow via the OAuth 2.0 Playground

Answer (score 2):

I got redirected to the same gws_rd=cr&ei url and it was because we were developing NOT in the USA.  Tried to VPN to Seattle and it then worked and redirected to the google.com homepage with result_code=SUCCESS.  I think Google is region blocking somewhere in the process.

Comment: This does not seem to be addressing what the question has asked.

Comment: Not sure how it doesn't? "I should be expecting the browser to be redirected to ...google.com/?result_code=SUCCESS&result_message=Accounts+now+linked, but my browser always gets redirected to https://www.google.co.in/?gws_rd=cr&ei=QDOEWfCAPMHA0gSUvJj4Ag and in the agent I still get accounts not linked message."  If you use the VPN as mentioned in my answer, you don't get redirected the the gws_rd=cr&ei.  If you look at his country on his Google redirect it's google.co.in - which doesn't redirect to google.com (which is the url where result codes are shown). @Phani can you try that?

Comment: Your answer assumes that redirecting from .com to .in is the only problem, but that isn't obvious at all. However, we can see if this suggestion works for OP.

Comment: It's a possible solution.  Especially because the url parameters after google.co.in are 
gws =google web server
rd = redirected
cr = country reffered. which is why the VPN worked.   Perhaps using a VPN isn't obvious to you.

Comment: Yep - just used the VPN to see if I we can get successful codes if requesting from USA.  I am wondering if there is some kind of region locking to account linked actions for USA only for now.

Comment: @Faltek thank you for y our answer, Yes, it works if I proxy from US. But, I can't expect all my users to live / proxy from US to have a seamless account linking with my agent.

Comment: We're both from outside the USA I presume - I wonder if we're missing something.  Will update thread if I find out.